# cannot find paper-button.html

Tags: polymer, bower, polymer-2.x

I'm new with Polymer. Doing this tutorial: https://auth0.com/blog/build-your-first-app-with-polymer-and-web-components/

My problem is my project cannot find the file http://127.0.0.1:8081/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html

I did installed it with bower:

```
bower install PolymerElements/paper-button --save
```

And the directory is created, but there is no .html file in it.

So when I try to include it in my component

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
```

I get a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest versions of the PolymerElements on bower are actually es module versions.

To get the Polymer 2 / HTML Import versions, install

```
PolymerElements/paper-button@^2.1.3
```

Comment: hmmm fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-button^2.1.3.git/': The requested URL returned error: 400

Comment: ah .. bower install PolymerElements/paper-button@2.x helped